# Distrubuted Cache platform for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, distributed-caching

I've got a .NET website and an API interface which sits on top of a VPS (Virtual Server). They both use ASP.NET Caching system (which is pretty nice and comfortable).
If it matters - the API system will be ported to WCF at some time.

I want to get ready to move from 1 VPS to multiple VPS (when we grow bigger) - thus I need some distributed Cache System.

Ideas would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several products that provide this, some open source, some commercial.  My personal preference is [Microsoft's AppFabric Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731.aspx) (which is free).

Comment: Thanks. is there any special reason it's your preference?

Comment: Pros: It's free.  It's supported by Microsoft.  It was built for .NET.  It works.  Cons: Setup is complex if you need the high availability features.